# TrasnslationAPI a bytes-like object is required, not 'Repeated'

Tags: python, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate a pdf document from english to french using google translation api and python, however I get a type error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\troberts034\Documents\translate_test\translate.py", line 42, in <module>
    translate_document()
  File "C:\Users\troberts034\Documents\translate_test\translate.py", line 33, in translate_document
    f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Repeated'
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with writing to the file as binary, but I open it as binary too so I am unsure what the issue is. I want it to take a pdf file that has english text and edit the text and translate it to french using the api. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate

def translate_document():
  
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    location = "global"
    project_id = "translatedocument"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Supported file types: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    with open("C:/Users/###/Documents/translate_test/test.pdf", "rb") as document:
        document_content = document.read()

    document_input_config = {
        "content": document_content,
        "mime_type": "application/pdf",
    }

    response = client.translate_document(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "target_language_code": "fr-FR",
            "document_input_config": document_input_config,
        }
    )

    # To output the translated document, uncomment the code below.
    f = open('test.pdf', 'wb')

    f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)
    f.close()

    # If not provided in the TranslationRequest, the translated file will only be returned through a byte-stream
    # and its output mime type will be the same as the input file's mime type
    print("Response: Detected Language Code - {}".format(
        response.document_translation.detected_language_code))


translate_document()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug on the sample code (I'm assuming you got the sample from the Cloud Translate API documentation).

To fix your code, you do need to use `response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs[0]`. So basically changing this line:

```
f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs)
```

by:

```
f.write(response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs[0])
```

then your code will work.